# Share express port over processes in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

So I switched from `child.fork` to `cluster.fork` to spawn chatbots that I run, as clusters share tcp ports. However, I can't seem to get the clusters to listen on the same port.

code:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var express = require('express');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  cluster.fork({path:'hello'});
  cluster.fork({path:'goodbye'});
} else {
  var web = express();
  web.get("/"+process.env.path,function (req,res){
    return res.end("hello, "+process.env.path);
  });
  web.listen(3000);
}
```

This is half working. I get no `EADDRINUSE` errors now, but only one of the paths is showing up.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working for lots of reasons.

1. `express.express` dont exist. You are looking for plain `express` method
2. `process.evn` dont exist. You are looking for `process.env`
3. You are not returning anything to the client in your route. You should use `res.end` or another method to response the client. Check the [http module documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) or the [express one](http://expressjs.com/).
4. The workers can share tcp connections. The master can not.

Some code that works:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var express = require('express');


if (cluster.isMaster) {
  cluster.fork({path:'hello'});
} else {
  //this is in a required file
    var web = express();
    web.get("/"+process.env.path, function(req,res){
      res.end("hello world!");
    });
    web.listen(3000);
}
```

If you want to use more than one worker, just fork more in the `if(cluster.isMaster)` condition.

Comment: that was actually just a shoddily coded example, not a copy and paste. I can fix my typos, but I updated my code to something similar to your example, and I get `EADDRINUSE` becuase I can't have multiple forks using the same port.

Comment: Refer to the edit I made. It's a more closely related example to the code I have. (The actual code uses handlebars to actually render a view, and one view gets rendered, but the rest return `cannot GET /path`)

Comment: Dalton, did you ever find a solution?